# Kubernetes does not resolve Pod from a different namespace without FQDN

Tags: kubernetes, dns

Let's say we have two namespaces `namespace-a` and `namespace-b`.

Pod `pod-name` running in a `Deployment` and exposed internally as a `Service` `service-name` via `ClusterIP` on `namespace-a`. The Kubernetes 1.17 cluster has a cluster domain name `cluster-domain`. The `cluster-domain` is not the default `cluster.local`.

Another Pod `batman` on `namespace-b` attempts to resolve the IP address of `pod-name`.

1. The following works from `batman`:
   `ping/telnet pod-name.service-name.namespace-a.svc.cluster-domain`
2. The following **does not** work from `batman`: `ping/telnet pod-name.service-name.namespace-a.svc`

However, if `batman` is running on `namespace-a`:
3. The following **does** work from `batman`: `ping/telnet pod-name.service-name.namespace-a.svc`

Is this related to DNS configuration? Is this how it supposed to work? I could not find any material specificly about this issue.

Comment: What is your `dnsPolicy` set to?

Comment: @Crou it is the default, that is, `ClusterFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `cluster.domain` instead of the default `cluster.local` you need to configure the local domain in the kubelet with the flag `--cluster-domain=cluster.domain`

Also you need to modify the ConfigMap for the CoreDNS Corefile to change the default

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.domain in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

To verify you check the `/etc/resolve.conf` file inside pod

```
search default.svc.cluster.domain svc.cluster.domain cluster.domain google.internal c.gce_project_id.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.10
options ndots:5
```

Comment: The custom cluster domain is correctly set by Kubespray, I think that is not the problem. It is working, except between different namespaces **and** when Pod is referenced *without* the cluster domain. See the question above. I'm sorry I think you did not address my original problem, which is very specific to omitting the cluster domain name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is how it's supposed to be working.

I can recommend reading [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution), where you can find [Are DNS queries being received/processed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-queries-being-received-processed)

> You can verify if queries are being received by CoreDNS by adding the  `log`  plugin to the CoreDNS configuration (aka Corefile). The CoreDNS Corefile is held in a ConfigMap named  `coredns`. To edit it, use the command …
>
> `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns`
>
> Then add  `log`  in the Corefile section per the example below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

> After saving the changes, it may take up to minute or two for Kubernetes to propagate these changes to the CoreDNS pods.
>
> Next, make some queries and view the logs per the sections above in this document. If CoreDNS pods are receiving the queries, you should see them in the logs.

You can also check [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/).